Why Laravel "limit" clause for relationships doesn't work as expected?
I have basically this database structure:

columns: id
posts: id
column_post: id, column_id, post_id

I'm trying to do it:
If I do this, it will return me all columns with all posts (in my case, all columns have more than 10 posts at least)
Column::with('posts')->get();

This also works fine, it orders the relationship as intended
Column::with([
    'posts' => function (Builder $query) {
         $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'); // this works fine
    }
]);

Here comes the issue, the limit(4), it sometimes will return me 0 results, even tho there's no column with 0 posts. Sometimes it returns 1 or 2 results. Why is this inconsistent behavior happening?
Column::with([
    'posts' => function (Builder $query) {
         $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4); // this doesn't work as intended
    }
]);

EDIT:
This only happens on Laravel 10 or lower, for Laravel 11 and higher, it was fixed.

Have you confirmed that getting a single column's posts works?

@user883992158 it returns a total of 4 Post records, but 1 for each Column model, instead of 4 Posts for each Column, then the 5ª Column shows no Post results

I just tested this and it works fine. You might need to add to your question

@user883992158 It was fixed on Laravel 11, I'll update my question and answer it with the article that explains the issue. For lower versions there's a lib to make it work.

OK, yeah, I tested it in L11. Glad you figured it out

To fix this you'll have to use this library if you're using Laravel <= 10: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit
This article covers the issue with more details: https://laravel-news.com/eager-load-limit
